# Can Display Objects have a Runtime Event in LUA?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I was thinking if my images can have a runtime event? like

while the app is running if a certain condition has met the object will trigger its runtime event.

```
myImage = display.newImage("MYIMAGE")

myImage:addEventListener("enterFrame", myImage)

myImage.occurence = onEventTriggered
```

im not sure if this code will work, i dont have LUA/Corona in my current computer

Comment: What do you mean by those 'certain conditions'? Do you need something like touch/tap listeners to all objects, without adding individual listeners to all..?

Comment: if z == 0 then the object will go there with the help of "transition.to", btw these objects are spawned, i don't need tap/touch it just keeps running on the application that's why I used "enterFrame"

Answer (score 1):

The enterFrame event is by Runtime only, but in the enterFrame handler, you can check the state of your object and do whatever checks are required to be done at every frame:

```
myImage = display.newImage("MYIMAGE")
local function enterFrame(event)
    if myImage.y == 0 then -- move it to 50, 50 in one second
         local settings = { time=1000, x=50, y=50 }
         transition.to( square, settings)
    end
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame)
```

With this technique, the enterFrame and object are independent: the enterFrame will be called once per frame, and in it you can check any object that is visible to the enterFrame function. If you have a table of objects, you would loop over the table contents. For example,

```
myImages = {}
local function enterFrame(event)
    for i, image in ipairs(myImages) do
        if myImage.y == 0 then -- move it to 50, 50 in one second
             local settings = { time=1000, x=50, y=50 }
             transition.to( square, settings)
        end
    end
    -- create new images: 
    local newImage = display.newImage("MYIMAGE")
    table.insert(myImages, newImage)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame)
```

Just be careful that if there is an existing transition on an object attribute, that transition must be cancelled before a new one is started. In this case you would put the return value of transition.to in a table and before starting a new transition, check to see if there is an item in that table; if yes, cancel it and remove it.

This gotcha related to transitions also applies if you use the per-object enterFrame event that Rob explained in another answer to your question. What is different is that with the per-object enterFrame, you don't need a myImages table. However, you do need to create your objects before the enterFrame is called, which is not the case of the global enterFrame. If you spawn objects at every frame, then what you want is a global enterFrame. OTOH there is no reason you can't use both:

```
local checkConditionPerObject(self, event)
     if myImage.y == 0 then -- move it to 50, 50 in one second
          local settings = { time=1000, x=50, y=50 }
          transition.to( self, settings)
     end
end             ...

local function spawn(event)
    local newObject = display.newImage(...)
    newObject.enterFrame = checkConditionPerObject
    Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', newObject)
end

local function enterFrameGlobal(event)
    if someCondition() then
        spawn()
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrameGlobal)
```

This provides a nice separation of concerns.

Comment: If "myImage" is inserted in a table, for some reason a new myImage will be created, will that myImage still contains its function? or will it be passed to the newly created myImage

Comment: @user3278528 I've edited to clarify and show how best solution is combination of both techniques (my global and Rob's per-object)

Answer (score 1):

You can do object based enterFrames.  They are still part of the Runtime object, but it can be a table handler instead of a function handler:

```
myObject = display.newImageRect("player.png",64, 64)
function myObject:doSomething()
   -- do stuff
end
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", myObject)
```

Comment: If "myImage" is inserted in a table, for some reason a new myImage will be created, will that myImage still contains its function? or will it be passed to the newly created myImage